# Writing message to Azure Service Bus queue from Azure function

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm trying to add a message to an azure message queue from an azure function.  To do so, I'm following this article where it has me add a reference to Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues

When trying to add this reference, the Azure function project in Visual Studio 2017 complains about the restricted version of Newtonsoft.Json (=9.0.1) relative to the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions reference.

> Version conflict detected for Newtonsoft.Json. Install/reference
>   Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.1 directly to project IHA.Functions to resolve
>   this issue.   IHA.Functions -> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 3.1.0 ->
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.2.2 -> Newtonsoft.Json (>= 10.0.1)
>   IHA.Functions -> Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.14 -> Newtonsoft.Json
>   (=
>   9.0.1).   IHA.Functions   C:\TFS\IHA\Misc\IHA.CSL\IHA.Functions\IHA.Functions.csproj  1

From what I understand, Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus requires Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.1.  If I remove the 9.0 version and add the 10.0 version, I can successfully add the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus package, but then the Azure Functions project complains that Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions requires 9.0 of Newtonsoft.

Based on these understandings, I can't seem to write to an Azure message queue from an Azure function.  Is this correct or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Azure Functions have explicit support for Service Bus in the form of extension.

You need to install the extension, see [Azure Service Bus bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus). Pay attention which Function App version you are using: 1.x with full .NET Framework, or beta 2.x with .NET Standard, and follow the corresponding guidance.

Then, instead of using Service Bus SDK directly, you would define and write to an [output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#output).

Comment: Thanks!  That worked perfectly and I edited the title. Appreciate the help!

Comment: does the python sdk support output binding for service bus? been looking for a while and am unable to find anything on this

Comment: Worth a separate question to be able to give a larger answer, but [yes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/tree/015855dae28eace3a74fdc7843eceef911a11ab4/tests/endtoend/servicebus_functions/put_message_return)